# flowtype: $Subtype seems broken for classes

Tags: flowtype

I think the following should fail:

```
class A { a: boolean; }
class B extends A { b: boolean; }

// this works, thus "proving" B is a subtype of A
const a: A = new B();

// however, this also works! It should fail.
class C { c: boolean; } // a C cannot be assigned to A, it's not a subtype
type SubtypeAcceptor<T> = ($Subtype<T>) => boolean;
const a2: SubtypeAcceptor<A> = (c: C) => (typeof c === 'object');
```

What gives? Non-generic versions of the above also fail:

```
type SubtypeAcceptorOfA = ($Subtype<A>) => boolean;
const a3: SubtypeAcceptorOfA = (c: C) => (typeof c === 'object');
```

Is this because, in theory, something can be `C & $Subtype<A>`? The above fails with exact object types as follows as well:

```
const a4: SubtypeAcceptor<{| a: boolean |}> = (c: {| b: boolean |}) => c.b;
```

Where I think it is obvious that `{| b: boolean |}` cannot be a subtype of `{| a: boolean |}`.